# Is there any method to compress ZIP files in python?

Tags: python, compression, zip, shutil

I have tried creating zip using zipfile and shutil. But, there was not visible file size compression in both the methods.

**zipfile**

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{directory_name}.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
```

**shutil**

```
shutil.make_archive(directory_path, 'zip', directory_path)
```

Is there any way to ensure file compression as well?

Thanks.

Comment: This may simply mean that your data is not compressible. If your data are things like images, videos, Microsoft office files, PDF files, then those are all already compressed and won't compress any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{directory_name}.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
```

[`zipfile.ZipFile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) state

> The *compresslevel* parameter controls the compression level to use when
> writing files to the archive. When using `ZIP_STORED` or `ZIP_LZMA` it has
> no effect. When using `ZIP_DEFLATED` integers `0` through `9` are accepted
> (see zlib for more information). When using `ZIP_BZIP2` integers `1`
> through `9` are accepted (see bz2 for more information).

Please try different `compresslevel` i.e.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{directory_name}.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=0) as zipf:
```

to

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{directory_name}.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as zipf:
```

then check if it does affect size of created file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need  `pathlib` module

from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED, ZipFile

```
from os import PathLike
from typing import Union


def zip_dir(zip_name: str, source_dir: Union[str, PathLike]):
    src_path = Path(source_dir).expanduser().resolve(strict=True)
    with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for file in src_path.rglob('*'):
            zf.write(file, file.relative_to(src_path.parent))
```

or

Using `zipfile module` I would use the below code :-

```
import os
import zipfile
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Zipped_file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir('./my_folder', zipf)
zipf.close()
```

This should zip the contents of `my_folder` in a file `'Zipped_file.zip'`. and store it in the current `directory`.